# Date based salt check and moving to another timezone

Tags: spring-security, salt

I have a date based salt for our user password storage using Spring Security. The date is stored in MySQL without any timezone specific information. The salt function actually ends up using a java.sql.Timestamp during the salting process.

We are considering moving the server to another timezone and I'm wondering if this might affect the security check in some way

Update.
Ok, here's what I found

- Hibernate returns a Timestamp in stead of a Date
- Spring Security uses the toString method of the provided salt object
- The toString method of Date includes a timezone, which can spell problem if you move your server and your salt is based on it.
- However, the toString method of Timestamp doesn't include timezone information.
- So, if you create your salt date object as a Timestamp, you're golden
- However, the Timestamp returned by MySQL is truncated at second level, so I ended creating a Timestamp, truncating the nanoseconds and assigning it to my date.

Comment: It _shouldn't_ matter (but I'm not going to answer, because I don't actually know offhand). Out of curiousity though, which date are you using as the salt? The date that the user registered?

Comment: Yes, I had a big fight with my Hibernate / Spring / MySQL implementation (I won). I've updated my answer for posterity

Comment: That's good! What you might want to do now is answer your own question (and you can accept your own answer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've updated my question with the answer